# Can I format cell font colours in LibreOffice Calc with more than just red, green, or blue?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a row of cells with this user defined format:

```
[GREEN]0;[RED]-0
```

With this format, positive numbers are green, negative numbers are red.

The problem is that the default green is too bright and hard to read against the white background.

I'Ve tried using the names of colours provided in colouor palettes made available in the interface, but they don't seem to work. `Green 5` or `GREEN5` don't seem to be the right syntax.

Is there a way I can get a darker green?

Comment: One hackish way to do this: format all numbers with the desired color for positives, then apply the formatting for negative numbers only (i.e. `0;[RED]-0`). LibreOffice will override the color for the negatives only and leave the positives.

Answer (score 2):

According to the help file:

**Color**
To set the color of a section of a number format code, insert one of the following color names in square brackets [ ]:
CYAN  GREEN  BLACK  BLUE  MAGENTA  RED  WHITE  YELLOW

Which means that you only have a choice of 8 colors.

Answer (score 1):

If you use conditional formatting, you can apply whichever colour you would like. In the below example, I will assume a column containing the values 1 for ‘Yes’, 0 for ‘No’ and −1 for ‘Unknown’. I have created three styles, one called ‘Yes (green)’, one called ‘No (red)’ and one called ‘Unknown (grey)’.

## Step 1: Creating the styles

1. Start by creating a separate style for each colour you want.
2. In the tab `Font effects` for each style, select the desired colour.
3. Once all styles are defined and saved, exit, then select the area you want to apply these colour changes to; it is quickest to select either the entire column or the entire row – you can edit the area afterwards.
4. With the column selected, click `Format → Conditional formatting → Conditions`.
5. At the bottom of the box that pops up, you can edit the area. If, for example, you want the style to apply to column E, but not the first row (where you might have headings), edit `E1:E1048576` to `E2:E1048576`.
6. Now add as many conditions as you need. In my example, I set

   1. `condition 1` to `cell value equals 1`
   2. `condition 2` to `cell value equals 0`
   3. `condition 3` to `cell value equals -1`
7. For each condition, choose the desired style. In my example I set

   1. the style of condition 1 to ‘Yes (green)’
   2. the style of condition 2 to ‘No (red)’
   3. the style of condition 3 to ‘Unknown (grey)’

## Step 2: Restyling for value 0

Should you follow this example, you will notice that also empty cells will get formatted as though they have the cell value 0. To counter this, click `Format → Conditional formatting → Edit` (the bottom selection).

[image: Image of Format dropdown menu]

***Image 1:** the bottom option from the `Format → Conditional formatting` menu is selected.*

In the new properties window that pops up, select the area and choose `Edit`.
[image: Image of Edit conditional formatting window.]

***Image 2:** The desired area is selected, and from the bottom row, I select `Edit`.*

Condition 2 is set to `Cell value equals 0`; this is the one we need to edit.

1. Click the dropdown menu which states `Cell value` and select `Formula is`, `Function is` or its similar English equivalent.
2. In the empty formula box, input the formula `=AND(E2<>"";E2=0)`. Note that the cell value has to match the beginning of your area, so if your area is set to `E1:E1048576`, you need to change the formula to `=AND(E2<>"";E2=0)`. If in your language edition you use commas to separate clauses, replace the semicolon with commas.

   1. This formula first creates an `AND` condition; each condition is inclusive.
   2. The first condition states that E2 is not equal to empty space.

      - Another way to do this, is with `NOT(ISEMPTY(E2))`.
      - Yet another way to do this, is with `NOT(E2="")`.
   3. The second condition states that E2 is equal to zero.
   4. If both clauses are true, the conditional formatting returns true.
3. You may have to reselect your formatting style.

[image: Image of new function specifying to check for cell not empty and cell equals to zero.]

***Image 3:** The formatting conditions entered, as per the description above: E2 has to not be empty and E2 has to contain the value 0.*

## Result

Other formatting included, this is my result:

[image: Example of conditional formatting based on numbers -1, 0 and 1]

***Image 4:** In column E, entering values −1, 0 and 1, yields a grey unknown for the value −1, a very violent red no for the value 0, and a pleasant green yes for the value 1.*

## Notes

In case you find that the colour you have chosen missed the value by one or more rows, make sure the cell specified in your formula matches the first cell of your range.

[image: Example demonstrating that the reference in the formula matches the first cell in the cell range.]

***Image 5:** Example demonstrating that the reference in the formula matches the first cell in the cell range.*

If you desire to colour an entire row based on the value of a specific cell, add a dollar sign in front of the position you want to lock; if you want to lock to a column in the above example, `E2` *in the formula* would be changed to `$E2`; if you want to lock to a row in the above example, `E2` would be changed to `E$2`. If you want to lock to a specific cell, put a dollar sign in front of both values: `$E$2`.

Suggestions for ways to improve this answer are most welcome.